# Use cases when Lombok or Java 'var' is useful

Tags: java, var, lombok, java-10

`var` is not very handful when you're navigating through the code and investigating the code which is not clear at the first look.

When developers use not self-describing methods names you have to spend some time to understand what is real type of the variable. And if you use Lombok's `var` you will be tightly coupled with [Lombok](https://projectlombok.org/), so I do not use it very often in my code.

What are the useful use cases for using `var` in Java?

Comment: When developers use unhelpful names, there is not much that will work. Many languages things are made available mostly for the people who name things like they should be. var is a nice fresh breeze over `List<LocalDate>` and what else is a variable "dates" going to be, in the context where what you need to deal with is an ordered sequence of dates?

Comment: Java 10 added the var keyword to the language, so the usage is likely to only increase. It is mostly just a way to decrease the verbosity and redundancy of having to specify the type. That said, it can make things a bit more unclear when reading the code. I suspect that best practices will develop around it as it is used more.

Comment: "if you use lombok's var you will be tightly coupled with lombok" Lombok ships with delombok, a tool which strips out all Lombok usage. So no, you code will not be tightly coupled to Lombok. You can remove it whenever you want.

Comment: It's most useful when you are using the `new` operator. `List<String> foo = new ArrayList<>()` becomes `var foo = new ArrayList<String>()`. The type is unambiguous but Java's classic syntax requires that I repeat myself. When using `var`, I don't have to.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

#### Arguments in favor of `var`:

- `var` requires less typing. It's shorter and sometimes easier to read than let's say `Map<Integer, ArrayList<String>>`.
- `var` requires less code changes if a return-type of a method call changes. You only have to change the method call, but not every place it's used.
- `var` encourages a more descriptive name for variables. I.e. `var customer = new Customer();` rather than `var c = new Customer();`.
- When you have multiple variable under one another of different types, the names all line up if they're all `var`, which wouldn't be the case with the types itself (unless the types coincidentally all have the same length).

#### Arguments against `var`:

- `var` obscures the actual variable type. If the initializer doesn't return a clearly defined type, you may not be able to tell a variable's type.
- Using `var` is lazy. Although `var` is certainly easier to type than `Map<Integer, ArrayList<String>>`, if the variable name isn't named well, you'd have to search a lot deeper in order to know what it refers to.
- `var` makes it harder to know what the type of the underlying variable actually is.
- You can't use `var` in all cases. Like:

  - `var i = 1, j = 2;` - Only one variable is accepted for `var` at a time.
  - `var arr = {1, 2, 3};` - Arrays must be explicitly declared.
  - `var f = a -> a + " ";` - It cannot determine what type this lambda function is.
  - `var f = String::replace;` - Method references cannot be used, because they don't have a type of itself. [More info here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49578553/why-cant-the-var-keyword-in-java-be-assigned-a-lambda-expression/49578603#49578603)

Most of these are taken from [this post for when to use `var` in .NET C#](https://intellitect.com/when-to-use-and-not-use-var-in-c/), where the `var` keyword has been present since the beginning, whereas with Java it's only available since version 10.

Oh, and another big advantage of `var`: it's shorter for [code-golfing](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/tags/code-golf/info) (creating a program/function which does a certain task/challenge with as few bytes as possible). :) Probably the main reason why I don't mind that it was added, since I codegolf in Java (as well as .NET C#, 05AB1E, and Whitespace) pretty often.

Related: Java 7's diamond operator. `List<String> names = new ArrayList<>();` vs `List<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();`.

Personally I still use written out types instead of `var`, except for code-golfing. But maybe I just need to get used to it a bit more before using it more often. For readability, and making it clearer and easier to see the type without having to dig, I don't use `var` at all. As for Java 7's diamond operator, I only use it when I instantiate it directly after the field, but would not when I instantiate it elsewhere (i.e. I would use `List<String> names = new ArrayList<>();`, but not `List<String> names; /* ... some code here ...*/ names = new ArrayList<>();`).
In general it all comes down to preference, though.

Comment: I agree. My rule of thumb is to only use `var` in conjunction with `new`. In any other situation, it introduces ambiguity which I'd rather avoid.

Comment: @Michael Yeah, that's how I also felt about the diamond operator of Java 7, as I mentioned at the bottom. Our applications at work are currently still in Java 8, so I haven't had to work with `var` in a developer situation yet, but I can indeed see it being used at some direct initialization of variables. [It's also mentioned at the bottom of the C# .NET page I linked (section "_How I Use `var` and Suggest You Do As Well_").](https://intellitect.com/when-to-use-and-not-use-var-in-c/).

Comment: @KevinCruijssen you can actually use `var` when declaring any class with diamond operator, you have to only declare type on the right side, `var names = new ArrayList<String>();`