# How do I create a List of functions in Java?

Tags: java, list, java-17

How can I create an array or List of functions in Java 17 (or similar)?

Expected hypothetical usage:

```java
    var myListOfFunctions = List.of(this::myFunction, MyClass::someOtherFunction);
```

I get the following error:

> Object is not a functional interface

I intend to stream the functions and pass them the same data.

Comment: Do the functions all have the same signature?

Comment: Yes, naturally.

Comment: The problem is that there's not enough type information to infer the parameterization of `List`, so it defaults to `List<Object>`. Either replace `var` with the actual type (e.g., `List<Function<Foo, Bar>>`) or use a type witness (e.g., `List.<Function<Foo, Bar>>of(...)`). Replace `Function<Foo, Bar>` with the actual type you're using.

Comment: I didn't know about type witnesses (the List.<TypeHere>) before @NoDataFound's answer. Thank you for providing extra context.

Comment: The problem is similar to the one answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49578553/why-cant-the-var-keyword-in-java-be-assigned-a-lambda-expression/49581723#49581723.  The issue is not `var` per se, but that lambdas and method references do not have a standalone type -- they need to get their type from context.  This could be an assignment target or cast, but you need _something_ that says what functional interface you want.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, create a functional interface that represents the common signature of all the functions. Note: there may be an interface from the `java.util.function` package that can be used to represent the signature, so it may not be necessary to create a new interface.

```java
// for example
@FunctionalInterface
interface MyFunction {
    int f(int a, int b); // this must match the signature of each function
}
```

Then, create a `List` of that type.

```java
List<MyFunction> functions = List.of(this::myFunction, MyClass::someOtherFunction);
```

Comment: Thanks, this seems to be a more complete, suitable for a wider variety of visitors seeking an answer to this question.

Answer (score 2):

You have to help Java a little for this one:

```
var myListOfFunctions = List.<Function<String,Integer>> of(this::myFunction, MyClass::someOtherFunction);
```

This would generate a `List<Function<String, Integer>>`.

Comment: Or just don't use var...

Comment: Depends on the whim of the compiler: I'm pretty sure that JDT (Eclipse) will fail here.

Comment: Thanks. This has worked. It was a simple one input, one output function signature, so this suits my needs best.

Comment: @Michael The problem is not `var`, but that method references and lambdas do not have a _standalone type_.  There are many ways to provide a suitable target type for them, some compatible with `var`, but you have to provide _some_ type information so the compiler knows what functional interface you want the lambda/mref to be typed as.

Comment: @NoDataFound No, it does not depend on the whim of the compiler.  The behavior is entirely well specified, and any conformant compiler will get the same answer.

Comment: @BrianGoetz You know better than anyone that it was designed to make code more expressive. If you need a type witness, which a lot of developers don't even know exists as a feature, it's not really achieving that goal. "Problem" might be going too far, but that was your choice of words, not mine.

Comment: @BrianGoetz this issue https://github.com/eclipse-jdt/eclipse.jdt.core/issues/494 is one of those I call "whim": you would have to tell the compiler (jdt) the exact type you expect or it wont compile.

Comment: You can call it "whim", but it's not.  It's just a bug in the compiler implementation, which should be fixed.